# Is there an easy way to tell all the actions available in a restful webservice?

Tags: web-services, wcf, rest

If a webservice is exposed as an Odata, I could easily see all the objects it exposes and can easily manipulate those objects without having the need for any documentation. (For example if you add an Odata service in Linqpad, it shows you all the objects available and you could use Linq to manipulate them.)

If I consume WCF, I could just go to the WCF url to see all the actions available.

Similarly if someone gives me a restful url (not Odata, just plain rest), is there a way to tell all the objects/actions available?

Comment: It's easy to do if the developer has included a /help URL that gives you the kind of information that a WSDL would.